# SetState on object property in array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, state

In my state, I want to update an object property on the first item in an array of objects. The object property isn't changing, even though I am taking steps to ensure immutability.

```
this.state = { 
    myFruits: [{a: false, b: 2, c: 'apple'}, {'a': false, b: 4, c: 'kiwi'}, ...],
    otherCategory: {} 
}

/// further down the code in componentDidUpdate

{ myFruits } = this.state;

let copyFruits = [...myFruits];
let newFruit = { ...copyFruits[0], a : true };
// console.log(newFruit): {a: true, b: 2, c: 'apple'}
copyFruits[0] = newFruit;
// console.log(copyFruits[0)] = {a: true, b: 2, c: 'apple'}
this.setState({ myFruits: copyFruits  });

// the end result is the same as the original state, where the first item, apple, has a : false instead of expected a : true
```

This change is being made in componentDidUpdate, and I'm not sure if this has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your componetDidUpdate method is not getting called.
The code you have written here is perfectly fine.

```
class SolutionExample extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = { 
myFruits: [{a: false, b: 2, c: 'apple'}, {'a': true, b: 4, c: 'kiwi'}],
otherCategory: {} 
}
}
changeKey =() =>{
    let { myFruits } = this.state;
    let copyFruits = [...myFruits]
    let newFruit = { ...copyFruits[0], a : true };

copyFruits[0] = newFruit;
this.setState({ myFruits: copyFruits  });
}
componentDidUpdate()
    {
        // this method is called whenever the state is changed  }
render() {
    let { myFruits  }  = this.state;
    return (
        <div>

            <h1>Solution</h1>
            {myFruits.map((item) =>{
                if(item.a){
                    return(<h2>{item.b + '-' + item.c}</h2>)
                }   
            })}
            <button onClick={this.changeKey}>Change state</button>
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<SolutionExample />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Here is the link : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXYdWQ

Answer (score -2):

You can simplify your change to:

```
const { myFruits } = this.state;

let newFruit = { ...myFruits[0], a : true };

this.setState({ myFruits: [newFruit, ...myFruits.splice(1)]  });
```

Also, a better approach is to `map` and update the object that you need by an id or any unique identifier.

```
this.setState({
 myFruits: myFruits.map(fruit => {
   if(fruit.c === "apple") {
     fruit.a = true
     return fruit;
   }

   return fruit;
 })
})
```